# Determining a difference between two Bitmaps

Tags: image-processing, bitmap

I am looking for an efficient way to see if a bitmap has been modified.  The approach I am currently taking is using the method copyPixelsToBuffer(Buffer dst) in the Bitmap class for each image.  I can then compare these two buffers to see if there is a difference.

It does not look like the sameAs method provided in the Bitmap class is useful in this scenario.

Another way that I was thinking to implement it is using the .getPixel() method and compare both images, which would lack efficiency.

Comment: Method of what? What programming library/language?

Comment: I believe it's java, perhaps on Android?

Comment: developing on Android, sorry I forgot to specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are attempting to efficiently detect if an image has changed or not it would be better to calculate a SHA1 hash of the original image and store it.  Then when comparing the potentially changed image you only have to open the new image and Hash those bytes then compare to the 20byte hash of the original image.  If the two images are the same the hash value will be the same.  If the images are different the SHA1 hash will be different as well.

EDIT (base on comment feedback):
If your system expects lots of changes to occur frequently you could take a distributed sample the bits in the file for the hash. How many depends on number of pixels you would expect to change (based on historical data) and how many you need to sample in order to have a 95% statistical confidence interval.

If it said the files were the same then you could fall back to comparing every bit (or a stored hash of the full file).  That would speed up the process for scenarios where lots of changes were expected and you just want to confirm that a user actually made a change.

This would limit the number of times you would have to refer to the bits in the original file.

Comment: It should be noted that the hashing just introduces unnecessary overhead - you still need to iterate through the pixel + do other operations.  Even if you are comparing the images multiple times the hashing approach may not provide a benefit as in many scenarios you expect differences to be detected after just looking at a few pixels.

Comment: True, the hashing algorithm works well if you don't expect changes very often.  It tends to be less efficient if changes to images are the norm in your system.  The asker didn't specify the back scenario so we are left to guess.

Answer (score 0):

For simple comparison of two image data buffers, you could perform a binary search for changes.

This has the potential for improving upon a simple per pixel check since most changes to images are made in groups of pixels in close proximity, not just one pixel.

So, for example, if the array was length 100, you might check the indices in the following order.

Level 1 - 50

Level 2 - 25, 75

Level 3 - 12, 37, 62, 87

Level 4 - 6, 18, 31, 43, 56, 68, 81, 93

etc.

If you find a change, stop. Worst case scenario, there are no changes and you check every pixel.

Let me know if you were looking for something else or if you need help implementing it.

Comment: That doesn't sound very cache efficient. With a large image, you'll be jumping around memory. I believe it's better to do sequential compare.

Comment: @KevinHsu That depends on the situation, but perhaps you're right. If it is java/android, this question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011327/alternative-to-bitmap-getpixel

Answer (score 0):

Just get the buffers representing the image data and loop through the pixels comparing their values.